# Getting a symbolic link full path

Tags: linux, perl

I would like to get the symbolic link full path.

Consider the following:

`/path/to/folder/link.file` links to `/path/to/folder/original.txt`.

I need to acquire the **links'** full path and not the original file, such as:

```
$fullpath = abs_path("link.file");
```

will return `/path/to/folder/link.file` instead of `/path/to/folder/original.txt`.

I tried reading but couldn't get a working solution..

To clarify, the absolute path of the **link file** itself

Comment: [readlink](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readlink.html)

Comment: This returns the real path for the original file.

Comment: @jww, the asker wants to get absolute path to the **link file**, not to the *target file* like in the referenced question.

Comment: The `/path/to/folder/link.file` is the "full" (absolute) path since it starts with a  `/` so it appears that you don't want that.  When you say "_.. will return `/path/to/folder/link.file` instead of `/path/to/folder/original.txt`_" it appears that you have the absolute path of the link but want the absolute path of the target (contrary to what the previous sentence states).

Comment: @jww was right. I want the full absolute path of the link file and not the original file it points to.

Comment: @jww not a duplicate, since the link relates to absolute path of the original file

Comment: Yes, @Tsyvarev is right. I want the absolute path of the link file itself like states in the post

Answer (score 2):

Use a method that doesn't check the file system such as [File::Spec::Functions](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Spec::Functions)'s `rel2abs`.

```
[~]$ perl -MCwd=abs_path -e'CORE::say abs_path($ARGV[0])' tmp
/tmp/ikegami

[~]$ perl -MFile::Spec::Functions=rel2abs -e'CORE::say rel2abs($ARGV[0])' tmp
/home/ikegami/tmp
```

Of course, if you can guarantee it's a relative path, you could simply use the following:

```
[~]$ perl -MCwd=getcwd -e'CORE::say getcwd()."/".$ARGV[0]' tmp
/home/ikegami/tmp
```